# What in all the world is StreamPlot doing?

Tags: plotting, bugs

This really should not be hard:

```
StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> {Arrowheads[.02], Darker[Pink]}]
```

But this is the mess Mathematica turns this into:

[image]

The distribution is quasi-random, and there seem to be a number of wrong arrowheads thrown in randomly, too. I would classify this as a bug (or several of them). Are there decent work-arounds? I found that providing sets of StreamPoints also does not work as expected:

```
StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamStyle -> {Arrowheads[.02], Darker[Pink]}, StreamPoints -> {{{0.01, 0}, {0.01, 0.1}, {0.01, 0.2}, {0.01, 0.3}, {0.01, 0.4}}}]
```

[image]

We still get incorrect arrows, and the streamlines inexplicably stop after a short distance.

Comment: What version are you using? What result would you expect?

Comment: I get the same weird plot with `$Version == "13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)"`.  Not OP but I'd expect, for a stream plot this simple, just a bunch of evenly-spaced, equal-length arrows pointing up and right.

Comment: 13.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)

Comment: I would expect to see some nice equidistant lines at a 45-degree angle. For the second example, I would expect to see those streamlines continue to the bounds of the plot area. This is how it worked in version 12 and earlier.

Comment: Version 12 undoubtedly handled this much more elegantly, along the lines of what @Pirx mentioned. Not to mention the fact that the color in the style directive seems to be ignored altogether in the later version, whereas it worked in v 12.

Comment: `StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> {Automatic, Darker[Pink]}`

Comment: version 12.3 produces the same problem on m1 mma, big sur.

Comment: Removing the ArrowHeads directive removes the spurious arrowheads, yes, but the rest of the problems remain.

Comment: I think this deserves a e-mail to support@wolfram.com

Comment: I reproduce the problem both with versions 13.0.0 and 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64. It is worth to be reported to the support.

Comment: The problem is absent in version 8.0.4 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeFhq.png)). So it is a regression bug.

Comment: Even  worse result of `StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 StreamStyle -> {Arrowheads[.2], Darker[Pink]}]` in 13.0.0 on Windows 10.

Comment: The result of `StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` is strange too.

Comment: The horizontal arrowheads look like a bug, that doesn't reproduce consistently for me across machines/versions.

Comment: On V13.0: Seems to have to do with a constant vector field. Adding some not-too-small noise helps: `{1 + 0.005 Cos[100 x y], 1 + 0.005 Sin[100 x y]}`. Adding lots of points helps a bit, too: `StreamPlot[{1, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, StreamPoints -> {MeshCoordinates@DiscretizeRegion[Rectangle[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001]}, StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> {Arrowheads[.02], Darker[Pink]}]`