# How to plot field line with exact starting and ending position continuously

Tags: plotting, streams

As the title suggested, I want to plot the electric field lines with exact starting and ending position continuously.
The code is like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];(*Spiegelladungen,1/4.*)\[Epsilon] = 1;
vc0 = 0.8 10^3;
a = 0.3/10^3;
b = 18/10^8;
dx = a;
n1 = 20;
n2 = 3;
k1 = 1/6;
k2 = 1/6;
\[Delta]1 = a/n1; \[Delta]2 = b/(2 n2 + 1); s1 = k1 \[Delta]1; s2 = 
 k2 \[Delta]2; c = a - 2 s2; d = b - 2 s1; \[Delta]3 = 
 c/n1; \[Delta]4 = d/(2 n2 + 1); n = n1 + 2 n2 + 1;
sp = 0;
xa[1] = Join[Table[0, {i, 1, n2 + 1}], Table[i \[Delta]1, {i, 1, n1}],
     Table[a, {i, 1, n2}]] + a/2;
ya[1] = Join[Table[(b + \[Delta]2)/2 + i \[Delta]2, {i, 0, n2}], 
    Table[b, {i, 1, n1}], Table[b - i \[Delta]2, {i, 1, n2}]] - b/2;
xb[1] = Join[Table[s2, {i, 1, n2 + 1}], 
    Table[s2 + i \[Delta]3, {i, 1, n1}], Table[a - s2, {i, 1, n2}]] + 
   a/2;
yb[1] = Join[Table[(b + \[Delta]4)/2 + i \[Delta]4, {i, 0, n2}], 
    Table[b - s1, {i, 1, n1}], 
    Table[b - s1 - i \[Delta]4, {i, 1, n2}]] - b/2;
Table[xa[i] = xa[1] + (a + a) (i - 1), {i, 2, 4}];
Table[ya[i] = ya[1], {i, 2, 4}];
xb[2] = xb[1] + a + dx + a/2;
yb[2] = yb[1] - b/2;
Table[xb[i] = xb[1] + (a + a) (i - 1), {i, 2, 4}];
Table[yb[i] = yb[1], {i, 2, 4}];
(*x-coordinates of the field points.*)x1 = 
 Join[xa[1], xa[2], xa[3], 
  xa[4]];(*y-coordinates of the field points.*)y1 = 
 Join[ya[1], ya[2], ya[3], 
  ya[4]];(*x-coordinates of the source points.*)x2 = 
 Join[xb[1], xb[2], xb[3], 
  xb[4]];(*y-coordinates of the source points.*)y2 = 
 Join[yb[1], yb[2], yb[3], yb[4]]; 
p0[i_, k_] := (1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) Log[(((x1[[
            i]] - (sp - x2[[k]]))^2 + (y1[[i]] - 
           y2[[k]])^2) ((x1[[i]] - (sp - x2[[k]]))^2 + (y1[[
            i]] - (0 - y2[[k]]))^2))/(((x1[[i]] - 
           x2[[k]])^2 + (y1[[i]] - y2[[k]])^2) ((x1[[i]] - 
           x2[[k]])^2 + (y1[[i]] - (0 - y2[[k]]))^2))];
p = Table[p0[i, k], {i, 1, 4 n}, {k, 1, 4 n}];
vc = Join[Table[vc0, n], Table[vc0, n], Table[-vc0, n], 
  Table[-vc0, n]];(*Voltage of electrodes.*)\[Lambda] = 
 LinearSolve[p, vc, Method -> "Multifrontal"];
pf0[x_, y_, 
   k_] := (1/(4 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) Log[(((x - (sp - x2[[k]]))^2 + (y -
             y2[[k]])^2) ((x - (sp - x2[[k]]))^2 + (y - (0 - 
              y2[[k]]))^2))/(((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2) ((x -
             x2[[k]])^2 + (y - (0 - y2[[k]]))^2))];
v[x_, y_] := Sum[pf0[x, y, k] \[Lambda][[k]], {k, 1, 4 n}];
ex0[x_, y_, 
   k_] := (\[Lambda][[
      k]]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) ((x - 
        x2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2) + (x - 
        x2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (0 + y + y2[[k]])^2) - (-sp + x + 
        x2[[k]])/((-sp + x + x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2) - (-sp + 
        x + x2[[k]])/((-sp + x + x2[[k]])^2 + (0 + y + y2[[k]])^2));
ey0[x_, y_, 
   k_] := (\[Lambda][[
      k]]/(2 \[Pi] \[Epsilon])) ((y - 
        y2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2) + (0 + y + 
        y2[[k]])/((x - x2[[k]])^2 + (0 + y + y2[[k]])^2) - (y - 
        y2[[k]])/((-sp + x + x2[[k]])^2 + (y - y2[[k]])^2) - (0 + y + 
        y2[[k]])/((-sp + x + x2[[k]])^2 + (0 + y + y2[[k]])^2));
Ex[x_, y_] := Sum[ex0[x, y, k], {k, 1, 4 n}];
Ey[x_, y_] := Sum[ey0[x, y, k], {k, 1, 4 n}];
Enorm[x_, y_] := (Ex[x, y]^2 + Ey[x, y]^2)^(1/2);
h0 = b; h1 = 50 10^-6 + b/2; h2 = b + 10 10^-5;
(*********************************)
StreamPlot[{Ex[x/1000, y/1000], Ey[x/1000, y/1000]}, {x, -3000 a, 
  3000 a}, {y, 1000 b/2, 7000 a}, PlotTheme -> "Scientific", 
 StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> {Black, Thin}, 
 StreamPoints -> 10, StreamScale -> Full, PlotRange -> All]
```

Sorry for the unclear code, you may only need to focus the last line using streamplot.

The plot is like this
[image]

The electric field line should be continuously, wo the red circle areas should have field lines too. But the plot doesn't show field line in these areas. How can I solve this problem.

Any questions will be appreciated. Thank you!

According to the answer in this question [StreamPlot symmetry](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134134/streamplot-symmetry) .

Ndsolve can be used to plot field lines.

```
Ex := Sum[ex0[x/1000, y/1000, k], {k, 1, 4 n}];
Ey := Sum[ey0[x/1000, y/1000, k], {k, 1, 4 n}];
sp3 = Join[Table[{x, 0.05}, {x, -1, -1.0/12, 1.0/12}], 
   Table[{x, 0.05}, {x, 1.1/12, 1, 1.1/12}]];
ode = {x'[t], y'[t]} == ({Ex, Ey} /. {v : y | x :> v[t]});
Graphics[{Red, PointSize@Large, PointPoint@Fold[Drop, sp3]}];
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{ode, {x[0], y[0]} == {aa, bb}, 
    WhenEvent[Abs[x[t]] > 1 || Abs[y[t]] > 2 , "StopIntegration"], 
    WhenEvent[-1 < x[t] < 1 && Abs[y[t]] < 0.05, 
     "StopIntegration"]}, {x, y}, {t, -10, 10}, {aa, bb}, 
   MaxSteps -> 10000, MaxStepSize -> 0.1];

sols = psol @@@ sp3; // AbsoluteTiming
(*{0.402537,Null}*)

Graphics[{Gray, Arrowheads[0.01], 
  Arrow[Transpose@Through[#["ValuesOnGrid"]] & /@ sols[[1 ;; -1]]]}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02]]
```

But The plot I generated is like this:[image]

The figures are not matched, so there must be something wrong with the code. Anyone can help to fix the code?

Comment: There is a small error in your code.  The ;; before h2 should be a single ;.  I don't quite understand what you are looking for but does StreamPoints -> 50 fix your problem?

Comment: @ Carter Thank you for pointing our that error. Sorry for my unclear description. I may want to produce field line like this: https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ElectricFieldLinesDueToACollectionOfPointCharges/ . The line in the example are continuously, while using streamplot the line seems always disapeared at some areas.

Comment: I think I see. Is it that you want 1) no streams to stop or start within the rectangular domain and 2) all stream lines to continue to the edge of the domain?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262387/what-in-all-the-world-is-streamplot-doing

Comment: @Michael E2 Hi, Michael, I'm not familiar with some of the syntax in your example. Could you please have a look for the code? Thank you very much for your time.